# How can I hot deploy using the glassfish adapter in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Has anyone gotten the glassfish v3 adapter to work with Eclipse without restarting every time there's a code change? I tried to set this up but the adapter "republishes" every time I change any file, which is very annoying. It takes up to 3 minutes and locks up my machine for a second.

I must remember to constantly stop the adapter before making any changes. I'd settle for just disabling this "feature", but even if I uncheck "publish change immediately" this behavior still happens.

I'm using the latest version of the glassfish adapter and tried with eclipse 3.5 and the 3.6 milestone builds....

What setup is everyone using if you have glassfish v3 as your server? Is there any way to actually get the hot deploy feature to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did a test and configuring the adapter to **Never publish automatically** works as expected:

[image]

With this setup, I have to publish changes manually.

I'm using Eclipse 3.5 with the latest version of the GlassFish v3 adapter. It just works.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about that screen...it doesn't work if you initally check never publish automatically when you first set up the server (which is what I did). You have to go to that screen after it's been set up and take that approach. That was driving me crazy...

Comment: How do you get to this screen??? I have been through every possible menu in Helios. I agree, the hot deploy/hot swap feature is not usable at all with glassfish. It is actually much worse than using an ant script to repackage and deploy a war...

Comment: I found it. Open server perspective, and double click on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is 'hack' that I use and works fine with maven, eclipse & GF4 hot deployment. Navigate inside your workspace where you have you xhtml project. 
open .project file
edit

```
<buildCommand>
   <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
   <arguments></arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Modify to:

```
<buildCommand>
   <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
   <triggers>incremental,</triggers>
   <arguments></arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

It works just fine for, but it might cause weird build issues (haven't tried for a long time so can't really say so use with case.)